# How to have a conditional SEPARATOR in a GROUP_CONCAT MySQL select

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know if this can be done or not. In my MySQL code one of my selects is:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(timestamp SEPARATOR '~') AS times
```

What I'd like to do is test the timestamps for being equal at the date/hour/min level and if it is replace the SEPARATOR with a `<br>`
instead of the tilde. Is there a way to do this in MySQL? If not how would I go about doing it in PHP? The end result needs to be the two (or more) timestamps making a string, which will be used in a table cell. If the date/hour/min are equal then both would be in the same cell. If it helps the timestamps would almost certainly be sequential in the table.

Comment: You could just use `DISTINCT timestamp` to remove the repeated values. You should add `ORDER BY timestamp` into the `GROUP_CONCAT` if they are not guaranteed to be sequential.

Comment: The problem is I need both timestamps, because they absolutely will have different seconds, even if the date/hour/min are the same.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? [Edit] the question and also add the `CREATE` statement for the table, sample data as `INSERT` statements and the desired result.

Comment: V5.5.59 but I don't understand the rest. Can you give me an example please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would typically do that with two levels of aggregation. First aggregate by minute and `group_concat` with the `<br>` separator, then aggregate the resulting string again with the `~` separator.

Assuming a table called `mytable` with a timestamp column called `mytimestamp`, you would do:

```
select group_concat(gc0 order by myminute separator '~') gc1
from (
    select 
        date_format(mytimestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') myminute,
        group_concat(mytimestamp order by mytimestamp separator '<br>') gc0
    from mytable
    group by myminute
) t
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=db9c2c23473beb9498d8a157016d95a8)**:

Sample data:

```
| mytimestamp         |
| :------------------ |
| 2019-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 2019-01-01 00:00:01 |
| 2019-01-01 00:00:10 |
| 2019-01-01 00:01:00 |
| 2019-01-02 14:10:00 |
| 2019-01-02 14:10:30 |
```

Query results:

```
| gc1                                                                                                                              |
| :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| 2019-01-01 00:00:00<br>2019-01-01 00:00:01<br>2019-01-01 00:00:10~2019-01-01 00:01:00~2019-01-02 14:10:00<br>2019-01-02 14:10:30 |
```

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need. But I can't figure out how to get the rest of my variables out of mytable. I know I didn't mention them but how would I pull out the value of 'call' as well. It is not grouped in the select but the table is GROUP BY call?

Comment: @KeithDKaiser: now you see why commenters of your question asked for you to provide sample data and expected results... But, basically, you need to put all columns that you want to return in both thte `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clause of the subquery and of the query.

Comment: Like this? But it failed.... select 
          callsign,
          COUNT_OF_TIMESTAMP,     
          group_concat(gc0 order by myminute separator '~') gc1
         
from (
    select 
     callsign,
      COUNT(timestamp) AS COUNT_OF_TIMESTAMP,
        date_format(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') myminute,
        group_concat(timestamp order by timestamp separator '<br>') gc0
    from TimeLog
    WHERE netID = 1698
    group by myminute, callsign, COUNT_OF_TIMESTAMP
) t